# Проблема с обновлением текста в QLineEdit PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Я пишу небольшое приложение и мне необходимо запускать определенную функцию сразу после того как пользователь что-то ввел в поде ввода.

Я реализовал это так:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from time import sleep


def function():
    sleep(2)


class Input(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self.main_window = main_window

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        function()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.input = Input(self)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема в том, что введенный пользователем в `Input` текст появляется не сразу, а только после выполнения функции, что не очень удобно.

Как исправить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте `time.sleep` в основном потоке - **это блокирует интерфейс**.

> void QTimer::**singleShot**(int msec, const QObject *receiver, const char *member)
>
> Эта статическая функция вызывает слот через заданный интервал времени.
>
> Эту функцию очень удобно использовать, потому что вам не нужно возиться с timerEvent или создавать локальный объект QTimer.

```
import sys
#from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QApplication, \
    QWidget, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


def function(letter):
    print(f'Hello World -> {letter}')
#    sleep(2)


class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self.main_window = main_window

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
#        function()
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda letter=event.text(): function(letter))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()            
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.lineEdit = LineEdit(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
#        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так чтобы не ждать всяких обновлений таймеров. И никаких задержек интерфейсов. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QApplication, \
QWidget, QGridLayout
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
     def __init__(self, main_window):
         super().__init__(main_window)
         self.main_window = main_window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.centralWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
    self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
    self.initUi()
    self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.press)
def press(self):
    print(self.lineEdit.text())

def initUi(self):
    self.lineEdit = LineEdit(self)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```